# Magento wishlist sidebar and main view only return last 3 added items

Tags: magento

We have a Magento site running version 1.4.1.1 that we have modified to be a catalog (no price) type store at http://geyer-rental.com.

We have engaged the wishlist functionality.

Issue.

The wishlist view.phtml and the sidebar only show the last three items added although the RSS feed and the wishlist data in admin >> customers show the complete list.

In a test example the item link in sidebar shows that there are 6 items in the wishlist only the last three added show.

Any suggestions on how to show all wishlist items would be deeply appreciated.

TIA 
Buck

Answer (score 5):

I guess the simplest way is in the `wishlist.phtml` template, before any items are shown, do the following:

```
<?php $this->getWishlistItems()->setPageSize(6); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, but fixed by changing the option **Display Wishlist Summary** to **Display Item quantities**.

[image]